# Order of promise in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

If I call a function ,which returns a Promise object , sequentially several times would the order of execution of those async operations be same as the order in which Promise objects were created?

Comment: I don't think so, the first one to resolve will come back first not necessarily being the first one to be called.

Comment: No, order will not be the same

Comment: I suppose it's *first come first serve*

Comment: That's not what he's asking and the answer is *yes*, the order would be the same, but when they're finished would not be the same.

Comment: It depends very much on the implementation of the function that you call. No, promises do not in general give any such guarantee.

Comment: What I understand is that JS is is single threaded. So if there are multiple async operations to be executed, then does it mean that they are queued up and executed one by one OR is it that JS would switch thread from one operation to other?

Comment: If you create a promise based on user action (say a filter button) and then just set the UI with the result as they come in (promises resolve) then you have a problem. User may select ABC but promises resolve ACB so last user action was C but UI is showing B. Common (bad) way to handle this is to prevent the user from doing anything until promise is resolved. You could however let the user do what they want and only set the UI if it was the last started promise with [something like this](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/lib/blob/master/src/index.js#L430-L476)

Comment: Even though your code runs on one thread when you do something like `fetch(url);fetch(url)` there could be multiple threads fetching (parallel) because the fetch method is native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of the function, and by what you mean by "the execution of those async operations."

Typically, a function returning a promise synchronously starts an asynchronous operation, and that's all it does: **Start** the operation. The operation then continues and completes independently of the function that started it.

So if you do this:

```
var p1 = foo(1);
var p2 = foo(2);
var p3 = foo(3);
```

...and `foo` synchronously starts an asynchronous operation when you call it, then yes, the async operations will be **started** in the order the promises were created.

That **doesn't** mean they continue or complete in that order, and indeed they very well may not. It depends on the operations in question.

Example:

```js
function foo(value) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("starting " + value);
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("completing " + value);
      resolve(value);
    }, value == 2 ? 800 : 200);
  });
}
var p1 = foo(1);
var p2 = foo(2);
var p3 = foo(3);
// Naturaly, in real code, we'd have error handlers on those
```

`foo` starts the operations in order, but they complete out of order, because the operation for `2` takes longer than the operations for `1` and `3`.

Answer (score 1):

The order of execution of promises will be the same as the order in which the promises were created, yes but they won't necessarily resolve in the same order. They will resolve whenever their task is completed like api request is completed and we get the data.