# How to not alter my array order in a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, here-api

I'm currently making a routing system using the here-api. I start with an array of directions in text. Like this.

```
directions: [ 
        "2 Rue de l'Euron, 54320 Maxéville",
        "34 Rue Sainte-Catherine, 54000 Nancy", //aquarium
        "401 Avenue de Boufflers, 54520 Laxou", //grand frais 
        "42 Rue Kléber, 54000 Nancy", //regalo pizza
        "33/45 Avenue de Metz, 54320 Maxéville", //lidl
        "2 Rue de l'Euron, 54320 Maxéville"
    ]
```

I send those directions to the here API to have lat and lng of those directions. The problem is that I use promises and sometimes those directions return in a diferent order, but I need at least the first and the last one to stay in their same place.

I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659172/order-of-promise-in-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563657/how-to-resolve-promises-in-order). I have already tried with await but I can't because is an asynchronous function. And without the promise; but it says it needs a callback.

This is how I get my coordinates with here's geocoder

```
getCoordinates(query) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    this.geocoder.geocode({ searchText: query }, data => {

                        //Si il y'a une response
                        if(data.Response.View[0].Result.length > 0) {
                            data = data.Response.View[0].Result.map(location => {
                                return {
                                    address: query,
                                    lat: location.Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude + "", //.toString() marche pas 
                                    lng: location.Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude + ""
                                };

                            });
                            resolve(data);
                        }
                        //Si non
                        else {
                            reject({ "message": "No data found" });
                        }
                    }, error => {
                        reject(error);
                    });
                });
            },
```

And here I try to receive them onLoad

```
load(directions){
     directions.map(direction => 
         this.getCoordinates(direction).then(response => 
              console.log(response[0]))
                )

            }
```

Sometimes I have the response like this. Not ordered

```
{address: "2 Rue de l'Euron, 54320 Maxéville", lat: "48.70283", lng: "6.13316"}
{address: "401 Avenue de Boufflers, 54520 Laxou", lat: "48.69347", lng: "6.13732"}
{address: "33/45 Avenue de Metz, 54320 Maxéville", lat: "48.70848", lng: "6.16666"}
{address: "2 Rue de l'Euron, 54320 Maxéville", lat: "48.70283", lng: "6.13316"}
{address: "34 Rue Sainte-Catherine, 54000 Nancy", lat: "48.69507", lng: "6.18847"}
{address: "42 Rue Kléber, 54000 Nancy", lat: "48.68373", lng: "6.16838"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log the responses only after calling `Promise.all` on the mapped promises for each direction:

```
load(directions){
  Promise.all(
    directions.map(direction => this.getCoordinates(direction))
  )
  .then((coordinates) => {
    coordinates.forEach((coordinate) => {
      console.log(coordinate);
    });
  });
}
```

`Promise.all` takes as a parameter an array of Promises, and resolve to an array of every Promise resolve value, *in the same order as the original array* - which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Great, it works. But I would like to know how does that Promise.all works? whats the difference between the then after .getCoordinates and after that Promise.all. btw could you upvote my question to give you upvote too.

Comment: `Promise.all` takes as a parameter an array of Promises, and resolve to an array of every Promise resolve value, *in the same order as the original array* - which is exactly what you want. eg `Promise.all([Promise.resolve(2), Promise.resolve(3)])` resolves to `[2, 3]`